# Using Merge Layer in Keras using Dot Product

Tags: merge, deep-learning, keras, word-embedding

I am trying to merge two layers together. My input, or my processed data, appears as such:

```
[[2069 2297 3087 ...,    0    0    0]
 [2069 2297 3087 ...,    0    0    0]
 [2069 2297 3087 ...,    0    0    0]
 ..., 
 [2711 4215  875 ...,    0    0    0]
 [5324 1412 1301 ...,    0    0    0]
 [5065 3561 5002 ...,    0    0    0]]
```

With each row representing a sequence of words and each #, a specific index to a word. I have two of these data and I am trying to merge them together by first embedding them into 16-dimensional word vectors and then using a dot product. To do this, I created two branches to embed the data first. I then try to merge them.

When I try to merge the two using this function in Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge( [x1_branch, x2_branch], mode = 'dot'))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected merge_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (162, 1)
```

I believe that the matrix multiplication was executed, as written and described in the documentation:

```
"E.g. if applied to two tensors a and b of shape (batch_size, n), the output will be a tensor of shape  (batch_size, 1) where each entry i will be the dot product between a[i] and b[i]."
```

Obviously, my batch size for this sample is 162. However, the error still makes no sense. How can the merge layer expect an input if it has already, seemingly, done the calculation?

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us a whole model definition?

Comment: The error seems to be with the layer to which you feed the merge layer, not the merge layer itself

Comment: Oh, sure. The merge model documentation is here: https://keras.io/layers/merge/ ----- Do you want my entire model?

Comment: I figured it out guys and gals. Thanks for all of the help!